# How to prevent ice cream from melting without a refrigerator?

Tags: food, substitute-tool, kitchen, storage, appliances

There are times when you are at work where you have the best ice cream parlor in town around the corner from your office. But you want to take the ice cream home and enjoy it there. Is there a way to keep the ice cream from melting at work without storing it in a refrigerator or ice box (which is unavailable at work) for at least 6 hours ?

P.S: The ice cream is given in a plastic container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Buy a thermos, they are generally cheap and they help insulate things to stay cold, not just hot!

P.S Also put some ice in the thermos to have extra coldness.

Comment: I don't see the 'life hack' in this...

Comment: Mostly because the answer to the question wasn't a lifehack. Don't blame the player, blame the game ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of buying the ice cream at the start of your shift, buy it at the end of your shift. If there's some reason you can't do that, then bring a cooler filled with ice. If a cooler doesn't work, then buy a mini-freezer and bring it to work.

Comment: A cooler with dry ice in it works well too, but it will make the ice cream especially cold.

Comment: Not really much of a lifehack tho.

Comment: @djsmiley2k [Relevant meta post](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/should-we-be-downvoting-conventional-answers)